# Can we have a "not override a concrete method ..." compile time error when implementing interfaces?

Tags: java, oop, interface, overriding, compiler-errors

Can we have a "*not override a **concrete** method ...*" compile time error when implementing interfaces ?

An example to be more clear :

I build up a framework containing interfaces. To use the framework developers need to implements some interfaces.
But if they don't override `equals(Object object)` and `hashCode()` `Object` methods the internal API logic will be broken !!

All that is mentioned in the javadoc but I want to have a **compile time error** or maybe a **runtime exception** when an interface is implemented without overriding some **concretes methods**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Java ships with annotation processor capabilities, starting from Java 6: [Source Code Analysis](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2008/04/10/source-code-analysis-using-java-6-compiler-apis.html).  (Technically it's part of Java 5, but Java 6 integrated it into the compiler phase rather than a special tool).  Sun provides this [Getting Started guide](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/apt/GettingStarted.html).

An annotation processor gets invoked by the compiler while building the project, and may issue errors just like the compiler does.  It's a neat way to enforce more rules than Java specifies.

Here is a sample Processor that would perform the check you desired:

```
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_6)
@SupportedAnnotationTypes("*")
public class CheckMethodOverride extends AbstractProcessor {
    // returns true if the class has a method with the specified method name
    // and specified number of parameters
    private static boolean hasMethod(TypeElement clazz, String methodName, int arity) {
        for (ExecutableElement method : 
                 ElementFilter.methodsIn(clazz.getEnclosedElements())) {
            if (method.getSimpleName().equals(methodName)
                    && method.getParameters().size() == arity)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    // the interface whose subclasses must override hashCode and equals
    TypeMirror interfaceToCheck;

    @Override
    public void init(ProcessingEnvironment env) {
        interfaceToCheck = env.getElementUtils().getTypeElement("com.notnoop.myinterface").asType();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations,
            RoundEnvironment roundEnvironment) {
        for (TypeElement e :
            ElementFilter.typesIn(roundEnvironment.getRootElements())) {
            if (this.processingEnv.getTypeUtils()
                     .isSubtype(e.asType(), interfaceToCheck)
                && (!hasMethod(e, "equals", 0)
                    || !hasMethod(e, "hashCode", 0))) {
                processingEnv.getMessager().printMessage(Kind.ERROR,
                    "Class " + e + " doesn't override hashCode or equals", e);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

The annotation processors can be specified directly in the compiler options (by adding `-processor com.notnoop.CheckMethodOverride` to the compiler options), or adding a `META-INF/services` file to your classpath which contains the name of the processor (`com.notnoop.CheckMethodOverride`).  The forlder `META-INF` can live in the root source directory of the project (or resource directory if using maven).

This works with any command line compiler.  I have no idea how to activate it in the IDEs though.

Comment: I don't fully understand this, but it looks amazing, and probably an elegant solution to the OP's problem. +1.

Comment: This is a nice example of using "Class Literals as Runtime-Type Tokens" in annotations, http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/extra/generics/literals.html. It's reminiscent of Neal Gafter's "Super Type Tokens", http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that with interfaces, but you can do that with abstract classes. E.g.

```
public interface Entity {
    //...
}

public abstract class AbstractEntity implements Entity {

    @Override
    public abstract boolean equals(Object other);

    @Override
    public abstract int hashCode();

}
```

and tell developers to extend `AbstractEntity` whenever they want to implement an `Entity`.

If you really want the rule to be enforced you'd need some sort of runtime check, like a bean post-processor in Spring.

Comment: +1: It was my first thought ... but I wanted to keep a free option for developers to inherit from others classes :) ... but you're right it's probably the easiest way ...

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid SO is the wrong place to ask. We answer questions about languages, we don't make the languages.

Sun has a Community Process in place where you can make suggestions for improvement or outright bug reports. I can dig you up links if you like.

I suspect it won't get done, though. If it wasn't considered a good idea until now, it probably won't be.

Something to help you in the short run might be standalone style checking programs. 
[CheckStyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) comes to mind, it's probably the biggest name out there, it's free-as-in-beer and offers a WEALTH of options. I suspect, but I'm not sure, that "not implementing `hashCode()` and `equals()` is somewhere in there too.

Comment: +1 : thx for the CheckStyle link I never heard about it ... but in this case I think your idea of a self made hashCode() and equals()  method will be more appropriate ...

Comment: Luckily Java/Sun provided a mechanism to enforce that!

Comment: Carl, I don't think the OP wants a language change.  Instead they are hoping to find a solution within the language as it exists.

Comment: @Peter: Yep, looks that way. It seems notnoop demonstrated a great solution.

Answer (score 1):

I just thought of a possible alternative:

Your interface (or possibly abstract methods) could specify methods (e.g.) `equals2()` and `hashCode2()`. These would be mandatory to implement to any implementor of the interface, of course. You could thus force your library consumers to code *something*.

And your library classes, that work with implementors of your interface, could then use these "custom" functions as replacements or implementations of the "real" functions, and to the re-definition themselves.

It's not a very elegant concept, and not very fleshed out, but you may be able to make something of it.